# Why does Ubuntu allow me to only upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 Alpha Release?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 12.10, and I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04. But what is weird is that Ubuntu only allows me to update to 'Ubuntu 13.04 Alpha Release.

I don't get it. Some people say to go to software sources, and in the 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' section I have to select 'For any new version' but that doesn't even help. The link of the screen shot of 'Software Sources' is here:

[image]

Here is the link of the screen shot of the window that asks me to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 *Alpha Release*:

[image]

Or is it because Ubuntu didn't release a FULL version of 13.04? I don't think that's right, so please help me.

Comment: I think everything is fine. I don't see any "Alpha release". 13.04 is working fine. Just hit upgrade and follow the wizard.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In your second screenshot, where does it say Alpha Release? It looks like a normal 13.04 upgrade. If there's another window that shows "Alpha Release", take a screenshot of that.

Comment: Try this from terminal `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, does it work?